# Asp.net MVC empty ViewResultBase.Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I read a book Pro ASP.NET MVC 3 Framework. I have a little problem with unit test. When i run this test, it not passed because result variable is null.

```
             // Arrange
            // - create the mock repository
            Mock<IProductRepository> mock = new Mock<IProductRepository>();
            mock.Setup(m => m.Products).Returns(new Product[] {
                new Product {ProductID = 1, Name = "P1"},
                new Product {ProductID = 2, Name = "P2"},
                new Product {ProductID = 3, Name = "P3"},
                new Product {ProductID = 4, Name = "P4"},
                new Product {ProductID = 5, Name = "P5"}
            }.AsQueryable());

            // Arrange - create a controller and make the page size 3 items
            ProductController controller = new ProductController(mock.Object);
            controller.PageSize = 3;
            // Action
            ProductsListViewModel result = (ProductsListViewModel)controller.List(2).Model;
            // Assert
            PagingInfo pageInfo = result.PagingInfo;
```

ProductController:

```
        public ViewResult List(int page = 1)
        {
            ProductsListViewModel viewModel = new ProductsListViewModel
            {
                Products = repository.Products
                .OrderBy(p => p.ProductID)
                .Skip((page - 1) * PageSize)
                .Take(PageSize),
                PagingInfo = new PagingInfo
                {
                    CurrentPage = page,
                    ItemsPerPage = PageSize,
                    TotalItems = repository.Products.Count()
                }
            };

            return View(viewModel);
        }
```

I'm new in mvc but what is strange for me, it's that in WebUI project everything works great. List of product display without any problem.

Comment: I found the solution, i used mvc 4 in tests project and mvc 3 in web ui project.